# Sum depending on value of Column B and Date in Column C

Tags: google-sheets, date

Column `A`: Name
Column `B`: Date (mm/dd/yy)
Column `C`: Value

I want to sum column `C` every time column `A` is a specific name & the corresponding date is before 2020

Small sample/Example of what I'm trying to work out:

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C10, A1:A10, "=Bob", B1:B10, "< Date(2020,1,1))
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it has to do with inputting the date for "criteria 2"

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use dates alongside `SUMIFS`

either using the `DATE` function

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$10, $A$1:$A$10, "=bob", $B$1:$B$10, "<="&date(2019,12,25))
```

or the actual date

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$10, $A$1:$A$10, "=bob", $B$1:$B$10, "<12/25/2019")
```